# Как проверить подлинность токена при авторизации бота в Телеграм?

Tags: python, telebot, авторизация

Не понимаю, как проверить подлинность токена бота. Думал это будет проще, через `try..except`, оказалось совсем не так. Я только начинаю пробовать **telebot**, ещё не все знаю.

Пробовал через `ExceptionHandler`:

```
class ExceptionHandler(telebot.ExceptionHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print("Error token")

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TOKEN, exception_handler=ExceptionHandler)
```

Видимо он не ловит ошибки авторизации. Подскажите, как правильно произвести проверку токена?
Хочу, чтобы ошибка была собственно написанной (Типо, проверьте токен, с ним что-то не так).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут можно сделать проверки ошибки, но чуть другим способом: отправить какой-либо(любой) запрос с токеном и уже дальше ловить ответ верный или нет

```
import telebot
import telebot.apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TOKEN)

try:
    bot_info = bot.get_me()
except telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException:
    print("Ошибка токена, проверьте его на правильность")
else:
    print("Бот авторизован")
```

Comment: Не знал, что есть `apihelper`, спасибо большое!